# как выстроить слова по частоте встречания?

Tags: java, сортировка

у меня есть текст, я смотрю смотрю сколько раз это слово встречалось в тексте. И записываю в HashMap слово и сколько раз оно встречалось.
Но у меня не получается выставить их по частоте встречания например:

> мороженое 6 были 4 улыбка 1

```
    try {
        List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]));
        for (String line : allLines) {
            String[] col = line.split("\\s+");
            HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
            for (String word : col) {
                if (!wordToCount.containsKey(word)) {
                    wordToCount.put(word, 0);
                }
                wordToCount.put(word, wordToCount.get(word) + 1);
            }
            for (String word : wordToCount.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(word + " " + wordToCount.get(word));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно что-то в этом духе...

```
    Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]), Charset.defaultCharset()).stream()
            .flatMap(words -> Arrays.stream(words.split(" ")))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .forEach(w -> System.out.println(w.getValue() + " " + w.getKey()));
```